# Find matching image borders using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors

I am implementing an algorithm to find images that can be stitched together side by side. 
Given image A, I want to find an image B that will give smooth color change  inside the red rectangle or at least, make the border between the images less apparent.
[image]

The most simple solution would be to take the color average at the border and compare, but I want to see if anyone has a better solution. What color, features, other than average color, would lead to better matching?

I am using C++ and OpenCV to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple color features, I'd recommend you to use keypoints such as SIFT, SURF etc. Once you find the keypoints, then you can match them in pairs and check which pair has the most keypoint matching. It's quite easy to implement it in OpenCV.

Comment: I do not see how key point features help me get smooth transitions between images. I am not trying to stitch images together into something like panoramas.  I only want to look at the right border if image A and the left border of image B and pick image B such that the border between them is not visible(if possible). Sorry if I am misunderstanding you answer, but I don't see how SIFT or SURF (which have no color information) can help here.

Comment: "I am implementing an algorithm to find images that can be stitched together side by side." gave that impression. However, coming back to your question; assuming the images are from different scenes, simple YUV histogram, Color Structure Descriptor, Color Layout Descriptor might be useful. Moreover, you may want to give a chance to texture similarity by using Local Binary Descriptors. They are very simple yet quite effective.